# How do you determine the direction of an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

$$\vec E(x,t) = 10\hat y \sin (50\pi x+10^5t+\pi/2)$$

Why for this electric field of a wave is the direction the wave traveling the negative $x$ direction? Why is it negative? And what does the unit vector $\hat y$ at the beginning signify?

Answer (score 3):

Why is it negative?

Take a parabola for example: $y = x^2$.  The vertex is at (0,0).  In other words: the height $y$ is 0, when the horizontal position $x$ is 0.

Now imagine that we allow it to move horizontally as time goes by: $y = (x+t)^2$.

Here's the question: after one second, at what horizontal position $x$ do you need to be so that the height $y$ is still 0?  Which means: find $x$ so that:

$$ y = (x + 1)^2 = 0$$

Clearly, $x = -1$ so that the inside of the bracket stays $0$.

So what that means is that as $t$ increases, $x$ must decrease for the height to stay the same.

It's the same with any function.  With your function, as $t$ increases, $x$ must decrease so that $50\pi x + 10^5t = 0$

As for $\hat{y}$, it means that the electric field points in the $y$ direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't familiar with vectors in general, remember that a notation such as:
$$\vec{D}=D\,\hat{u}$$
describes a vector $\vec{D}$ with a direction carried by unit vector $\hat{u}$, and with a projection on $\hat{u}$ equals to $D$.

As the notation shows, $\vec{E}$ is a vector. The expression that you gave indicates that it is carried by vector $\hat{y}$. This means that this electric field keeps a constant orientation along axis $y$ during propagation.

This is *completely* uncorrelated with the direcion of propagation. Let's have a look at a function like:
$$s(x,t)=\cos\left(\omega\left(t-\frac{x}{c}\right)\right)$$
Notice that if you add any length $l$ to $x$ and simultaneously add $l/c$ to $t$, the function keeps the same value:
$$s(x,t)=s\left(x+l,t+\frac{l}{c}\right)$$
So this describes a wave propagating along the $x$ axis at celerity $c$ in the *positive* direction.

In your question, you have a similar function, except that the sign of $x$ is reversed, so this wave travels in the opposite direction (hence the minus sign).

Comment: *completely* uncorrelated?  Could the direction of the electric field be the same as the direction of propagation?

Comment: @M.Enns That's not the common case, but an electromagnetic wave can have longitudinal fields (in a guide for instance).